# I am trying to change the color of the area under the actual JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

This is my output window.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohpFI.png]

I want to change the color of the blank area under the JTable which is in sort of gray color. I want to change it to the white.

Comment: Please provide more details and state what you want answered.

Comment: Have you tried setting its background (JTable.setBackground)?

Comment: Yes I Tried JTable.setBackground() but it will only change the background color of cells. Not the space under the JTable (i.e. In Sort of Gray color) I wanna make that empty space White just like background panel color.

Comment: What you see is the `JViewport` of the `JScrollPane`. You can use:   `table.setFillsViewportHeight( true )`. Then the area will be the same color as the background of the table. Or, if you want a different color from the table you can use `scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground( ... )`.

Comment: table.setFillsViewportHeight( true ) this works thank you very much.

Comment: @ManishTambe, the question was re-opened, so I added my comment as an answer. You can "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark beside the answer so people know that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to change the color of the blank area under the JTable which is in sort of gray color. I want to change it to the white.

What you see is the `JViewport` of the `JScrollPane`.

You can use:

```
table.setFillsViewportHeight( true ).
```

Then the area will be the same color as the background of the table.

Or, if you want a different color from the table you can use

```
scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground( ... );
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so everyone knows the problem has been solved.